# Enable all control in Form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, toolstrip

In my MDIparent I set some controls to enabled=false. How I will enable all controls including toolstrip items, menustrip items, menustrip subitems?

**This is the working code:**

```
public void EnableAllControls(Control.ControlCollection Controls)
{
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        c.Enabled = true;

        if (c is MenuStrip)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in ((MenuStrip)c).Items)
            {
                foreach (ToolStripItem e in item.DropDownItems)
                    e.Enabled = true;

                item.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        if (c.HasChildren)
            enableControls(c.Controls);

        if (c is ToolStrip)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripItem item in ((ToolStrip)c).Items)
            {
                item.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `enableControls`? I assume you're trying to call the method recursively, but the method you've shown here has a different name.

Comment: Do you not need to simply enable the tool strip rather than its items?

Comment: This is a classic XY question.  How did they get disabled in the first place?  The simple way to do that is to set the form's Enabled property to false.  Which disables all of its child controls as well.  Re-enabling it is now trivial, just set the form's Enabled back to true.  Your code doesn't work because ToolStripItems are not derived from Control so do not get added to the Controls collection.  They get added to the Items collection.

Comment: Rather than (confusingly) changing your question to the fixed code, you should post an answer with the fixed code instead.